# show row values vertical in crystal report graph(Cross Tab Chart)

Tags: .net, vb.net, crystal-reports, vb.net-2010, crystal-reports-2010

I have a crystal report graph(Cross Tab Chart) in which there are a lot of data to be shown. Row values are some names. Its not showing perfectly. If the name is shown vertical, it will be good.
please help me to make row values vertical in crystal report graphs.
[image]

I want show that student names vertical.

Comment: Can you add a picture of what you want to change?

Comment: @bendataclear:-I have uploaded the picture

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could remove the labels made by the chart. Then create your own labels that would be vertical..ie

```
S
t
u
d
n
a
m
e
```

But it would probably look better and I know at the very least easier to read if you just changed the orientation to horizontal, that way you wouldn't have to worry about the labels being vertical.
If you take that route...right click your chart and select chart expert, on the type tab select the horizontal instead of the vertical radio button down toward the bottom or the expert window.